# Web Py | How to set form.Dropdown args using db.select query

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

I am missing something rather simple but cannot figure out how to properly read a db.select query for use in form args.

Sample Code:

```
class index:
    form = web.form.Form(form.Dropdown(name='option',args=[]))

    def GET(self):
            dbresult = db.select('test')
            options = db.select('test',what='name',group='name')
            form = self.form()
            form.option.args = options
            return render.index(dbresult,form)
```

This return (Storage {'name': u'google'}) as one of the form args. All I want is google read back. I know I am missing something simple, any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class index:
    form = web.form.Form(form.Dropdown(name='option',args=[]))

    def GET(self):
            dbresult = db.select('test')
            options = db.select('test',what='name',group='name')
            form = self.form()
            form.option.args = [(o.name, o.name) for o in options]
            return render.index(dbresult,form)
```

[Dropdown](http://webpy.org/form#dropdown) args should be list or list of lists.  In `(o.name, o.name)` the first one is option's value (I usually set it to column's id), and the second one is its description. If they are the same, then `[o.name for o in options]` should work as well.